# Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

The question is generic but I'm using firestore and it's a NoSQL and no answer was able to fix this error. So I have a `useState`:

```
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
```

Then I am fetching the snapshot of documents in a collection and store it in an array:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection("Users").get().then((querySnapShot) => {
            let arr = []
            querySnapShot.docs.map((doc) => {
                arr.push({ id: doc.id, value: doc.data() })
            })
            setUsers(arr);
        });
    }, [db])
```

Then later in the code, I am using that array as:

```
            <p>Here is the list of all the users that are in the database: </p>
            {(users != null) && users.map((user, index) => (
                <ul key={index}>{user}</ul>
            ))}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong but I'm getting

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {id, value}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an
> array instead.

Comment: You have to enumerate the properties of `user`. If you replace `{user}` with some random text (to demonstrate the point) the error will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a user is an object or array, not a string for example, and putting that makes an error. use {user.name} or property of user instead of whole object/array.